# Posting a variable in a php script

Tags: php, html, forms

I wanna set the name of the file with a input field.
I already know you could such thing with a variable you need to set yourself

I tried this but it didnt work and I could find anything on the web either about this

```
$location
$ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/$_POST[$location].txt'
```

please help

Comment: try this `file_put_contents('/tmp/'.$_POST["location"].'txt'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$location = $_POST['location'];
$ret = file_put_contents("/tmp/$location.txt", $data);
```

You also need to set the second parameter (data).

But it is not such a good idea to use this and have you thought about duplicate names? If someone posts a name that already has been used.

https://www.php.net/file_put_contents